# balance column widths in a multicolumn table

Tags: tables, columns

I am trying to center the vertical line in my table between the 0 and 31. Does anyone know how to this? Below is my latex code.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[] \begin{tabular}{|c|cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|} 
\hline 
TEXT &  
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{TEXT TEXT} &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{TEXT TEXT} &  
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{TEXT TEXT} &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{TEXT TEXT} &  
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{TEXT TEXT} \\ \hline TEXT &  
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{TEXT TEXT} &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{TEXT TEXT} &  
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{TEXT TEXT} &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{TEXT TEXT} &  
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{TEXT TEXT} \\ \hline TEXT &    
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\centering 0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{31} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & 31 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & 31 &
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & 31 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & 31 \\ \hline
TEXT &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1
&   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 \\ \hline TEXT &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}
&   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &  
1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 \\
\hline TEXT &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 \\
\hline TEXT &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 \\
\hline TEXT &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 \\
\hline TEXT &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &   1 \\
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why all the `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` wrappers?

Comment: I was using the online latex table generator. This is what it gave me.

Comment: Thanks for providing this piece of information. In my opinion, it is precisely the habit of `tablegenerator.com` of encasing the contents of each and every single cell in a `\multicolumn` wrapper that makes the code almost unmaintainable later on. In short, the online site may be ok for a quick and dirty (usually, very dirty!) initial fix. But if one wants to build on this code in order to come up with a better "look", one has no choice but to get rid of all of the wrappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic `l`, `r` and `c` column types don't have fixed or predetermined widths. Instead, their widths end up being whatever cell in a given column happens to be widest. This is why the first column in each of the five pairs of columns is quite narrow, as all it contains are the numbers `0` and `1`; the second column's width is a residual, given by the width of the combined column headers ("TEXT TEXT") minus the width of the first column.

To fix this, I suggest you load the `array` package and employ its `w` column type instead of the `c` column type. The `w` column type takes as one of its parameters the column's desired usable width. This width may be computed from information available about the combined column headers; this is illustrated in the following example.

Just to make this example a bit more realistic/relevant for real-world tables, there are actually two different column widths to consider, as the strings in first two combined headers ("TEXT TEXT") are different from (*viz.*, longer than) those in the next three combined headers ("TEX TEX").

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type

%% Measure widths of widest column headers
%% for columns 2 thru 5 ("TEXT TEXT" is wider than "TEIT TEIT"):
\newlength\mylenA 
  \settowidth\mylenA{TEXT TEXT} % strings in 2 two-column headers 
  \setlength\mylenA{\dimexpr\mylenA/2-\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
%% for columns 6 thru 11 ("TEX TEX" is wider than "TEI TEI"):
\newlength\mylenB
  \settowidth\mylenB{TEX TEX}  % strings in 3 two-column headers
  \setlength\mylenB{\dimexpr\mylenB/2-\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c|}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] 
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional -- for a more open "look"

\begin{tabular}{| l | *{4}{wc{\mylenA}|} *{6}{wc{\mylenB}|}} 
\hline 
TEXT & \mc{TEXT TEXT} & \mc{TEXT TEXT} 
     & \mc{TEX TEX} & \mc{TEX TEX} & \mc{TEX TEX} \\ \hline 
TEXT & \mc{TEIT TEIT} & \mc{TEIT TEIT} 
     & \mc{TEI TEI} & \mc{TEI TEI} & \mc{TEI TEI} \\ \hline 
TEXT & 0 &31 & 0 &31 & 0 &31 & 0 &31 & 0 &31 \\ \hline
TEXT & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 
TEXT & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 
TEXT & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 
TEXT & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 
TEXT & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 
TEXT & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Each of the columns would need to receive the same width. One way to achieve this is by applying `X`-type column in `tblr` (requires `tabularray`). The only disadvantage of `tblr` is that code takes longer to compile.

EDIT.
In general, `X`-type columns create paragraph cells. This means content exceeding column width is automatically added line breaks. However, in this case, cells with long texts `TEXT TEXT` are merged. As a consequence, this feature gets cancelled. If you think
you will need auto line-breaks back, you have to add the fixed width to the `cell` specification, e.g. `cell{1-2}{2,4,6,8,10} = {c=2}{<unit length here>}` such as `2cm`.

In all cases in `tblr` environments, line breaks can be added explicitly, e.g. `{TEXT\\TEXT}`. Note for this to work, the content must be enclosed in braces `{...}`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \begin{tblr}{
            width=\linewidth,
            colspec = {c *{10}{X[c]}},
            column{2-Z} = {colsep=2pt},
            rows = {rowsep=2pt},
            cells = {font=\footnotesize},
            cell{1-2}{2,4,6,8,10} = {c=2}{},
            vlines, hlines,
        }
        TEXT & TEXT TEXT &
             & TEXT TEXT &
             & TEXT TEXT &
             & TEXT TEXT &
             & TEXT TEXT & \\
        TEXT & TEXT TEXT &
             & TEXT TEXT &
             & TEXT TEXT &
             & TEXT TEXT &
             & TEXT TEXT & \\ 
        TEXT & 0 & 31 & 0 & 31 & 0 & 31 & 0 & 31 & 0 & 31 \\
        TEXT & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 \\
        TEXT & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 \\
        TEXT & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 \\
        TEXT & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 \\
        TEXT & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 \\
        TEXT & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 & 1 &  1 \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should also mention that the `X` column type, which you're assigning to columns 2 thru 11, allows automatic line breaking of cell contents, as needed. Depending on the OP's actual use case (about which we admittedly know next to nothing), line-breaking inside cells may be either quite desirable or quite undesirable.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. I added a few words about line breaks. I doubt OP considered them at this stage but they still might be a follow-up request. It would be clearer if OP actually provided a more realistic example.